# Typescript - object as a private or protected

Tags: javascript, interface, typescript, private, protected

How can i define a object as a protected or private in Typescript ?

I can't do it in interface ( only public allowed ),
and I can't do that inside the class as well, because below doesn't work.

```
private options : interface{
    collapsible  : boolean;
    collapsed    : boolean;
    editable     : boolean;
}
```

Any hints ?
Thank you

Zoltán Tamási - Thank you for help,

**In the Interface**

```
declare module ICoreModule{
    // protected or private
    interface IOptions{
        initWhenDataReady   : boolean;
        collapsible         : boolean;
        collapsed           : boolean;
        editable            : boolean;
    }

    export interface ICoreScope extends ng.IScope{
        sandboxSave : Function;
        data        : Object;
    }

    export interface Class extends App.Directive{
        $scope   : ICoreScope;
        $element : ng.IRootElementService;
        $attr    : ICoreAttr;
        $ctrl    : ng.IFormController;
    }
}
```

**In the class:**

```
protected options : ICoreModule.IOptions = <ICoreModule.IOptions>{
    initWhenDataReady   : true,
    collapsible         : true,
    collapsed           : true,
    editable            : true
};
```

Comment: If you define an interface inside a module, you can export it or not. By not exporting it you can achieve a private-like behaviour on the module level.

Comment: Ah, great !  Exactly what I was missing. So private is possible, any hints for protected ?

Comment: Protected has no sense for classes or interfaces in this scenario. Protected can only be a member of a class, which means only subclasses can access it. By the way as far as I know TypeScript 1.5 supports protected members inside classes.

Comment: I'm using it exactly for inheritance. Got it solved now. In module declaration, something that is not exported, is private or protected, it allows to use protected or private in class - so it works fine now - thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you define a class or an intertace inside a `module`, you can choose wether you want to `export` it or not, using the `export` keyword.

If a class or interface is not exproted, then it is visible only inside the declaring module.

However, if a non-exported class or interface is used in any public member, method, etc. of an exported class, then you'll get a compile error and you'll have to export it then.